# how come that the variance of an estimate is smaller than the variance of the true value?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I'm reading [purdue intro to simple linear regression](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwiv24n7u9rIAhWEWBQKHWokCYM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.purdue.edu%2F~jennings%2Fstat514%2Fstat512notes%2Ftopic1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGd5SUtLhxygLv7CrwFguA4ViUARQ&sig2=JE2VO1l5KFXiW0rQpLJbTg&bvm=bv.105841590,d.d24&cad=rja), page 16. My understanding is that we're trying to estimate the expectation of the random variable $y_h$, that has variance $\sigma^2$. Our estimation itself is also random, dependent on the sample we picked to create our regression line. The variance of this estimation is given by $$\sigma^2(\hat y_h) = \sigma^2[\frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_h-\bar x)^2}{\Sigma (x_i -\bar x)^2}]$$ 
This quantity is less than $\sigma^2$! How is that possible? My intuition is that trying to estimate something which is already random, by using a *random* sample should be "twice as random" - and should have a larger variance...
What's wrong with my formula/intuition?

(statistics noob, please be patient if the question isn't well formed or doesn't make a lot of sense...)

Comment: What exactly is this "something which is already random"?  In the framework implied by your formula, the target of any estimator is a *fixed value* and is not random at all.

Comment: @whuber = why do you say that? Y is random, and has a variance of $\sigma^2$

Comment: You haven't explained yet what $Y$ is, but presumably it represents a response in a regression setting.  You appear to be *estimating* a parameter of the response distribution associated with the regressor value $x_h$.  That parameter is *not* random; it has no variance at all.  The *estimator* (presumably $\hat y_h$), being a statistic constructed from the responses, *is* random.

Comment: wow, really sorry for not following you, but I'm talkin about $y_h$, which *is* random! and to my understanding, it has a variance of $\sigma^2$. I was expecting the estimator $\hat y_h$ to have a greater variance. Let me know if this is complete gibberish and should I remove this question...

Comment: It's not gibberish, but it's quite confusing because you haven't yet explained your notation. Rather than hoping we'll guess correctly, please edit your post to include this essential information.

Comment: Agree @whuber, I've edited and tried to make it less sloppy and confusing, and added a reference. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Thank you.  The expectation of $y_h$ is a parameter: it is not random.  What you are asking about is not a regression phenomenon; it is basic to all estimation procedures. You might enjoy reading about laws of large numbers.